# Запись массива в Local Storage

Tags: javascript, localstorage

у меня есть html таблица, из двух колонок, необходимо по нажатию на кнопку записывать данные со второго столбца в local storage. при проверке инспектором кода, записан оказывается только последний элемент.

```
document.getElementById("clicMe").onclick = Compare;
function Compare(){
    // перебираем элементы и записываем в массив
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('td:last-child');

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var arr = [( elements[i].innerHTML )];
        //запись в харнилище
        //localStorage.td = JSON.stringify(td);
        localStorage.setItem("arr ", JSON.stringify(arr ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы на каждой итерации цикла записываете информацию по одному и тому же ключу, перетирая тем самым информацию, записанную на предыдущей итерации. Можно либо разово записывать весь массив целиком по одному ключу, либо записывать каждый элемент отдельно, но по уникальному ключу. Вероятно, первый вариант окажется удобнее.

Comment: Если говорить про идею @Regent с записью каждого элемента по уникальному ключу, то там будет примерно так: ```localStorage.setItem("arr-" + i, JSON.stringify(arr ));```. Но я согласен, что это крайне неудобный вариант.

Comment: Записала разоово массив целиком, все получилось))

Answer (score 2):

Извлеките массив данных, который хотите сохранить и запишите его целиком:

```js
var data = [...document.querySelectorAll('td:last-child')].map((td) => td.innerHTML);
localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(data));
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>x</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>y</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Считать массив обратно можно будет через 
`JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data");`.